# Newly generated Sprint Boot REST Application only returns 401

Tags: spring-boot, rest, kotlin

I have a newly created Spring Boot 3.0 application using Kotlin, which returns 401 on all HTTP calls.

MyApiApplication.kt

```
package com.my.app.api

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

@SpringBootApplication()
class MyApiApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<MyApiApplication>(*args)
}
```

TestController.kt

```
package com.my.app.api

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import java.time.LocalDateTime

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    fun test(): LocalDateTime {
        return LocalDateTime.now()
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
server.port=6020

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:6010/mydb
spring.datasource.username=mydb
spring.datasource.password=mydbpass
```

pom.xml

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.0.0-SNAPSHOT

```
<groupId>com.datadriven.headless.api</groupId>
<artifactId>headless-api</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>headless-api</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <kotlin.version>1.7.20</kotlin.version>
    <testcontainers.version>1.17.4</testcontainers.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <args>
                    <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                </args>
                <compilerPlugins>
                    <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                </compilerPlugins>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    ...
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    ...
</pluginRepositories>
```

"curl -v localhost:6020/api/test" returns always returns 401. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please share the pom.xml for further investigation.

Comment: Or build.gradle, if you use Gradle.

Comment: or try curl -v localhost:6020/api/test/

Comment: I shared a slightly shortened version, as seen by the three dots, as the whole pom.xml is too long (Stackoverflow won't let me post it).

Comment: 401!? -> Unauthorized! -> Spring security!

Comment: removing Spring security dependencies does not change anything

Answer (score 1):

You might be affected by [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/31852) issue.

Take a look here and try to see if your logs match the logs of the ticket. I think the issue is that spring boot when it does not understand the request it sends back the `error` page but the error page is also behind security by default and can't be disclosed, so then spring boot gives a 401 response instead of the `error` page.

Also [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11623) ticket is the current open ticket from `spring-boot` team to handle the above issue

Comment: Thank you! That helped me find the problem: I did not have a security configuration (see my own answer in this thread).

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following class solved my problem:

MyAppApiConfig.kt

```
package com.my.app.api

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityCustomizer


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class MyAppApiConfig {
    @Bean
    fun webSecurityCustomizer(): WebSecurityCustomizer? {
        return WebSecurityCustomizer { web: WebSecurity ->
            web.ignoring() // Spring Security should completely ignore URLs starting with /resources/
                .antMatchers("/api/**")
        }
    }
}
```